# jquery .blur() not working in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, blur

I have a html5 page and when it loads in IE9, I am getting 2 focuses on the page. One on a text box (when I click on the text box) and another on a button (which is present when the page loads). Is it possible to get 2 focus on the same page? Image attached.

[image: IE9 Screenshot]

I tried using jquery .blur() method but the focus is not getting removed in IE9. It works fine in FF and Chrome but IE9 just won't do it. Doesn't matter where I click on my page, the focus does not get removed. I used this to remove focus:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(document).blur();
    },100);
});
```

Anybody got any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: Which jquery version do you use?

Comment: @t.niese i am using jquery 2.0 (i guess that is the latest one)

Comment: `2.x` is the jquery version that removed most of the browser compatibility things (only targeting standart conform modern browsers) the 1.x versions (latest is `1.10.x` ) is the version that contains the browser compatibility code (both have the same features). IE always had problems with `focus` and `blur` events (i know IE 9 had some things fixed, but i don't know if everything). So you should test it with the `1.10.x` probably then your problem is solved (i can't test for myself right now, but it is likely that it could work)

Comment: Another note if you have such questions also provide some source. It is always be helpful to see what kind of `button` it is, to know why it is focused. Out of an image we don't know how the html code of the button looks like it could be a `button` or an `input`

Comment: @t.niese tried using jQuery 1.7 and 1.10... still not working. The button is of standard type `<button id='startButton'>Start</button>`

Comment: What does a `$(":focus").length` give you for a count?

Comment: its giving 1 as the answer in console